# How do I stop SSMS from editing my view query

Tags: ssms, sql-server-2017

Is there a way to force SSMS to use the exact query I paste into a view without it making changes? It is extremely annoying to me that I can write a working query and SSMS will make small or large changes to it that make it harder to read or not work at all. I have been trying to google this, but I have no idea how to put this into concise terms.

Example:

```
WHERE NOT(ClutchAssy.LineOpSta = '7701/040/004' AND LEN(TRIM(ClutchAssy.CompSN)) > 10)
 AND NOT(ClutchAssy.LineOpSta = '7701/030/003' AND LEN(TRIM(ClutchAssy.CompID)) >= 5)
```

gets turned into

```
WHERE (NOT (LineOpSta = '7701/040/004')) AND (NOT (LineOpSta = '7701/030/003'))
OR (NOT (LineOpSta = '7701/040/004')) AND (NOT (LEN(TRIM(CompID)) >= 5))
OR (NOT (LineOpSta = '7701/030/003')) AND (NOT (LEN(TRIM(CompSN)) > 10))
OR (NOT (LEN(TRIM(CompID)) >= 5)) AND (NOT (LEN(TRIM(CompSN)) > 10))
```

In this case, both WHERE statements seem to be functionally identical, but if I want to work on this view in the future it is extremely annoying to have to work from these changes rather than what I wrote myself. Does anyone know how to stop this from happening, or at least know why this happens? Thank you for helping me learn.

Comment: Please post the view definition. Is it materialized? How do you modify it? SSMS does not rewrite view/query by itself. Do you have some exntesion like Apex/Redgate/SSMS  Boost/Toolkit/... installed?

Comment: Where are you editing and viewing this query?  I have never had SQL Server or SSMS alter the definitions of the views I have created via `create view`, though the Query Builder tool will.

Comment: I am pasting the view into the form that pops up when I right click on views, and hit new view. I guess I should be using ```create view``` code instead.

Comment: So I went back to a view I was trying to create a few months ago that would break when I paste it in the designer window, and used ```create view``` instead. It works as a view now but breaks every time I open it in the designer window. Is there any way to make the designer not change my code? Or do I just use alter/create for everything? Thanks again guys.